# How can I use apply properly in R in this dataframe column?

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a dataframe  column with NA, I want to how can I use  apply (or lapply, sapply, ...) to the column.

I've tried with apply and lapply, but it return an error.

The function I want to apply to the column is:

```
a.b <- function(x, y = 165){
  if (x < y)
    return('Good')
  else if (x > y)
    return('Bad')
}
```

the column of the dataframe is:
   data$col = 180 170  NA  NA 185 185

When I use apply I get:

```
apply(data$col, 2, a.b)
 Error in apply(data$col, 2, a.b) : 
   dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I have try dim(data$col) and the return is NULL and I think it is because of the NA's.

I also use lapply and I get:

```
lapply(data$col, a.b)
Error in if (x < y) return("Good") else if (x > y) return("Bad") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This is for a course of R for beginners that I am doing so I am sorry if I made some mistakes. Thanks for taking your time to read it and trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` is used on a matrix, not a `vector`. Try:

```
a.b <- function(x, y = 165){
  if (is.na(x)){
    return("NA")
  } else if (x < y){
    return('Good')} else if (x > y){
    return('Bad')}
}
data$col=sapply(data$col,a.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this with `mapply` by specifying the values to pass into your parameters:

```
mapply(a.b, x = data[,'col'], y = 165)
```

Note that you may need to modify your `a.b.()` function in order to manage the `NA's`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues going on here:

- `apply` is meant to run on a something with a dimension to act over, which is the `MARGIN` argument. A column, which you're passing to `apply` has no dimension. see below:

```
> dim(mtcars)
[1] 32 11
> dim(mtcars$cyl)
NULL
```

- `apply` and `lapply` are meant to run over all columns (or rows if you're using that margin for `apply`). If you want to just replace one column, you should not use `apply`. Do something like `data$my_col <- my_func(data$my_col)` if you want to replace `my_col` with the result of passing it to `my_func`
- `NA` values do not return `TRUE` or `FALSE` when using an operator on them. Note that `7 < NA` will return `NA`. Your `if` statement is looking for a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value but getting an `NA` value, hence the error in your second attempt. If you want to handle `NA` values, you may need to incorporate that into your function with `is.na`.
- Your function should be vectorized. See circle 3 of the [R-Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Currently, it will just return length 1 vectors of `"Good"` or `"Bad"`. My hunch is what you want is similar to the following (although not exactly same if `x == y`)

```
a.b <- function(x, y = 165){
  ifelse(x < y, "Good", "Bad")
}
```

I beleive using the above info should get you where you want to be.